# laravel : how to set session with opening modal

Tags: php, laravel, session, bootstrap-modal

I have 2 buttons for 2 modals . in below code :

```
<div>
    <h3>1 month</h3>
    <button type="button" class="pay-btn-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Pay this featur</button>
</div>

<div>
    <h3>2 month</h3>
    <button type="button" class="pay-btn-2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2">Pay this featur</button>
</div>
```

I insert 2 modals in the footer :

```
<------ Modal 1------->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <?php
            Session::flush('month');
            Session::put('month', 1);
            ?>
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="{{ route('panel.vip.payment') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="plan">
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">pay</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

<------ Modal 2------->
    <div id="modal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <?php
            Session::flush('month');
            Session::put('month', 2);
            ?>
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="{{ route('panel.vip.payment') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="plan">
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">pay</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to clear the `month` session when any of the pay buttons are clicked and then the value for that button (1 or 2) set in the `month` session

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What happens after a button is clicked?

Comment: @vivek_23 , modal is opening. I want to set a custom session by opening each modal.

Comment: Then make an ajax request and change the session value

Comment: @vivek_23 , How can I do this?

Comment: Are there going to be multiple modals being opened in different tabs simultaneously?

Comment: @vivek_23 , no. I want to click on each button, set custom session. question have edited again.

Comment: Instead of dealing with sessions, you can just send that `1` or `2` in the form action URL itself.

Comment: try JQuery ajax https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . When someone clicks the button make a request to controller and change session.

Comment: dont put that session logic stuff in the view. It makes it really hard to manage.

Comment: @shihab is right, make a ajax request when you open a model. 
Because the php code will before the page is up. so jquery+php is your answer :)
You can do something like this $('#button_one').click( function () { //ajax request here });

Answer (score 0):

Button code :

```
<div>
    <h3>1 month</h3>
    <button type="button" class="pay-btn-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal1">Pay this featur</button>
</div>
```

Modal code :

```
<------ Modal 1------->
    <div id="modal1" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <form action="{{ route('payment') }}" method="post">
                    @csrf
                    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="plan">
                    <div>
                        <button type="submit">pay</button>
                    </div>
                </form>

                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

send ajax to PHP when clicked the button and removed session on the server-side.

see below code :

```
$('.pay-btn-1').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type   : 'post',
                    url    : '/clear-session',
                    data   : {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                    success: function (data) {
                        //
                    }
                });
            });
```

Now in the `controller` on `clearSession` method :

```
public function clearSession(Request $request)
    {

        $request->session()->forget('Vip');

        return response()->json('ok', 200);

    }
```